# Intent filter for opening local file

Tags: android, android-intent, text-files, uri, intentfilter

I'm struggling with [simple] task.

I have an activity that works with text files (or any text-like files).
And I need to run it from simple intent like this (**no schema**):

```
am start -a my.ACTION -d "/sdcard/file.txt"
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
unable to resolve Intent
```

I tried to use just simple filter:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="my.ACTION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But it doesn't work. I tried adding mimeType, pathPatterns, etc, but didn't success.

---

If I use:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="my.ACTION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and:

```
am start -a my.ACTION -d "file:///sdcard/file.txt"
```

Then everything works just fine. **Is there a solution? I read Intent filters documentation but didn't find any.**

Comment: "Then everything works just fine" -- so, use that. "Is there a solution?" -- you already described the solution.

Comment: No, it's not. I need to run it using intent without schema specified.

Comment: "I need to run it using intent without schema specified" -- that's not possible, unless you pass the data by some other means (e.g., an extra). The data facet has to be a valid `Uri`, and a valid `Uri` has a scheme.

Comment: Well, not really. We can read here: [uri.isAbsolute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#isAbsolute()) that it
_Returns true if this URI is absolute, i.e. if it contains an explicit scheme_. So not only explicit schema is possible, but also implicit one.

Comment: But an `<intent-filter>` will not honor that. Sure, for passing stuff around using an explicit `Intent`, you can get away without a scheme. If you want to go that route, go ahead, and specify the component in your `Intent`. Then, you not even need an `<intent-filter>`. Bear in mind that an `<intent-filter>` is for the use by other apps. Few if any will know about your custom action; few if any would use a scheme-less `Uri`.

Comment: It does. When I add `mimeType=text/*` to my filter and `-t text/*` to intent, then I can leave Uri/data without scheme and than it works. For some reasons I just try to make intent as small as possible, but documentation doesn't really say what happens when scheme is not present.

Comment: I can change action to `android.intent.action.VIEW` it doesn't change anything. And I can have _all-purpose_ app that does "something" with input. So I don't want mimeType, nor schema. And so-called _relative_ Uri is well defined as well.

Comment: Then pass the path via an extra, not the data facet of the `Uri`.

Comment: Yes, I found that solution. But still it's not very consistent for me, data-field looks like the one for passing file path. Well, thanks CommonsWare.